# How can I determine which JavaScript file makes my website slow?

Tags: javascript, html, web

My website is http://hoopweb.com/. It suddenly loads so slowly. I know that it is because of a JavaScript file. Can someone help find the file? I can't experiment on all files due to some reasons.

Comment: Useful reading: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/472495).

Answer (score 2):

You can open the developer tools and check in the network tab exactly which script is taking the longest time to load.

And as mayersdesign said, too many scripts = too many requests = longer page load time.

Answer (score 0):

http://v2.zopim.com/bin/v/widget_v2.195.js is particularly slow, but in general you simply have too many scripts and too many loading in the head and not the footer.